# Calculating the Number of times "Yes" appears in a column

Tags: calculated-column

I am using SPD 2007, Sharepoint 2007.  I have a list that has a column of Yes/No choices.  I need to calculate the number of times "Yes" is chosen.  Is there a way that this can be done with calculated columns?  And if so, what is the formula?  Thank you.

Comment: This can definitely be done (The solution, depending on your answers to the following questions, might be a little, well, 'creative' though). Do you need the number of Yes values in the whole list, for a view, or just for the items displayed on a page?  And how do you need to consume this value? Right on the page? As a column in a list?

Comment: I need the numbers in the whole list.  It will probably have to be stored to a column that won't be used for anything besides storage.  Once there, those totals need to be updated to another list, but that is for later.

Comment: We still need a little more requirements clarification. Do you need real-time data that is constantly being updated, or is this a one-time push to that secondary list?  And if I may what is the ultimate purpose of this number? Maybe we can find a simpler way to implement the business value you are trying to create.

Comment: Unfortunately it is real time.  Anytime the primary list gets updated with a yes or no value, the second list needs to be updated with the correct number of "yes" selections.  The number is just used as a quick reference, it is what the customer wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The easy way**: If all they need to do is see at a glance the number of Yes answers, just create a view on the list that groups items by that column.  You'll get the count totals out of the box.  You can then drop a list view web part that consumes that view anywhere you want on the site.

**The hard way**: If you go down the path of trying to store this value in a list, you are talking about a list item event receiver, which involves Visual Studio and farm code.

Comment: For now it will have to be a view.  I don't have access to the server for testing so this will have to be a temporary solution.  Thank you for all of your help and responding back so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate not with a Calculated column as they are calculated at the list item level plus they only get updated when the list item is being updated.

You could use a group list view and and aggregate count function. Alternatively look at something like the Data View Webpart.